# How to enable non technical users to use GitHub

Tags: git, github

We're currently storing two Dynamic CRM solutions in Github and have triggers to automatically deploy these solutions once a change has been pushed to the master branch.

This works really well in the development world, but we'd now like to hand over the system to relatively non technical users who will make system changes via a GUI and will then need to upload files to GIT.

GitHub doesn't allow the manual uploading of files. Is there a easy way to upload files to GitHub without using Git?

Update: The GIT workflow can be difficult to understand especially if have not worked with source control before. Our users may be able to push changes, but the first time a merge is required, the workflow would fall over. Ideally I'm looking for something with an interface like a SharePoint document library, e.g. a very simple upload and replace control.

Comment: There are a number of gui git clients, including one from Github (for mac and Windows).  Do any of these meet your requirements?  If not please describe the complete workflow of what you want the non-technical people to do along with what you have tried and why just teaching basic git commands doesn't work.

Comment: To me, this sounds more on topic for software recommendations SE than here

Comment: "Github doesn't allow the manual uploading of files" Yes, that is correct for the GUI, but the API does have facilities to create Commits via HTTP: https://developer.github.com/v3/git/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload into a git repository, at some level you have to use git. But, you don't have to expose git directly to the users. You can write your own code that handles the git operations behind the scenes and presents a simpler system to the users.

See: https://libgit2.github.com/ for library that would let you make git calls.

Of course, that means you'd have to write the tools to provide the workflow for your users. I don't know of any system that already provides it.